# vue js recommended library for datatable

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

What is the best library for `vuejs datatables` that is easy to implement and use especially with `laravel`? I need some opinions because im having a hard time implementing the datatables myself. Thanks

Comment: And what have you done to find it? What are the candidates that you find not good enough and why is that? Please explain. And don't expect people here to do the task for you.

Answer (score 4):

I am also in the process of finding a good table library for vuejs. As far as my research goes, I have found one library which works very well - vue-good-table. They have maintained a good documentation. You can see it here -

https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/
github url - https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table

In case you are also looking for in-line editing of data, I did not find good options. If you can go for a paid library, ag-grid (https://www.ag-grid.com/example-gallery/) is a rich library with vuejs support.